# Совмещение клиента Telegram userbot с GUI приложением

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram, pyrogram

Имеется приложение с GUI интерфейсом, реализованным в виде класса. Внутри него инициализируется и вызывается другой класс,  который по некоторому триггеру обращается к клиенту телеграм, так же вынесенному в класс, с передачей текстового аргумента. Клиент работает в режиме "Отправил сообщение --> Ждёт ответ в виде ГС --> Озвучивает полученный аудиофайл".

Проблема заключается в несрабатывающем хендлере (либо кривом старте клиента). Для вызова используется связка

```
self.gs_forward.app.start()
self.gs_forward.message(answer.replace(func_name, ''))
```

Стартуем клиент, хендлер, забитый на функцию озвучки, отсылаем сообщение-триггер, ждём вуаля, но срабатывает только отправка текстового сообщения. Полагаю, что это вопрос перебивающихся потоков, но ума не приложу, как это грамотно обставить. На данный момент инициализация объекта происходит внутри класса интерфейса, в главном потоке, обращение к нему - внутри функции, запущенной в отдельном.

```
import pygame
import THREAD_checker
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler
from pyrogram.types import Message
from pydub import AudioSegment

class gs_forward:
    def __init__(self, api_id, api_hash, dialog_chat_id):
        pygame.init()
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.dialog_chat_id = dialog_chat_id
        self.app = Client(name='me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

    def start(self):
        print('start')
        with self.app:
            self.app.add_handler(MessageHandler(self.voice_message)) #хендлер, нацеленный на голосовые сообщения
            self.app.run()

    def message(self, text):
        self.app.send_message(self.dialog_chat_id, text)  # Отправляем сообщение перед началом обработки

    def voice_message(self, client: Client, message: Message):
        client.download_media(message.voice, file_name="voice.ogg")
        self.convert("voice.ogg")
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load("output.wav")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            continue
        THREAD_checker.t = False

    def convert(self, input_file):
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_file, format="ogg")
        output_file = "output.wav"
        audio.export(output_file, format="wav")
```